# Outlook Macro not firing

Tags: microsoft-outlook, macros, microsoft-outlook-2013

My macro was working fine the other day, but as of today, it does not.

I have not changed the program, nor the code, nor updated via Windows Update. I use Kaspersky.

When the user clicks send, it fires the `Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)` function... This was working fine, and tested.

Today, when I click send, it does not fire that function. I've added a break point inside the function and it never enters debug mode on that breakpoint... However, the email is still sending.

Under Macro security, I've ensured the `Enable all macro's` is checked.

The code is in the ThisOutlookSession

Any idea what I can do to fix this?

Comment: Have you tried a system restore to a date before the issue started?

Comment: Actually, I didn't think of that, I will give it a go, thank you @CharlieRB

Comment: @MyDaftQuestions, any resolution for this?